# Can we pass a path string with white-spaces in it as argument to fopen()?

Tags: c, file-io, path, fopen

I'm using `fopen()` and I need to open a file where I pass a **path** with white-space in it as argument. Here is my code:

```
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("\this folder\myfile.txt","w");
```

Will that work as such or do I need to add something in there to recognize the space?Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just try ?

Comment: The best thing to find out for sure would be trying it out (hint: it's going to work once you replace `\\`s with `\\\`s, otherwise the first character would be a `TAB`).

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that this wouldn't cause a problem in particular first.  I felt like it was a pretty basic question.

Answer (score 5):

Spaces will work, but you need to escape `'\'` though, as

```
pFile = fopen ("\\this folder\\myfile.txt","w")
```

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing special you need to do if the path has spaces in it.

```
pFile = fopen ("\\this folder\\myfile.txt","w");
```

Should work. Note the required double back-slashes in strings.

Answer (score 0):

not pFile = fopen ("\this folder\myfile.txt","w");

should be pFile = fopen ("\this folder\myfile.txt","wb");

Comment: You must replace '\' with '\\' for path.

Answer (score 0):

Consider: `rawurlencode()`

If you are trying to load an external resource such as `http://domain.com/path/to/file/filename has spaces.php` then you might need to encode the url to avoid `fopen()` from failing.

In that case, you should actually call `rawurlencode()` since that will convert all necessary characters to `%XY` characters, including spaces. The regular `urlencode()` converts spaces to a `+` which won't help.

**Caveat:** I haven't tested this on an expansive list of character strings so it may create a different set of problems, but it worked for me in all cases I could find.